# How to change ReactJS styles dynamically?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I was trying to run ReactJS inside my twitter bootstrap web app. I have some issues using styles.

Having this div:

```
   ...
   <div class="ui-progressbar-value ui-widget-header ui-corner-left" style="width: 80%;"/>
   ...
```

I'm writing some dynamic progress bar, and would like to make that 80% change (look at ** underneath). So this is my code writing in JSX:

```
  var Task = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
  return (
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <span className="header">
        <span className="title">{this.props.type}</span>
        <span className="percent">{this.props.children}%</span>
      </span>

      <div className="taskProgress progressSlim progressBlue" >
        <div className="ui-progressbar-value ui-widget-header ui-corner-left" 
       **style="width"+{this.props.value} +"%;" />**
      </div>
    </a>
   </li>
  );
 }
});
```

I read some documentation about the [inline sytles](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html), but the example is very light.

Thanks for your help.

### Edit:

By using:

```
    style={{width : this.props.children}}
```

it works fine, but was just wondering how to force it as % instead of px.

Answer (score 104):

Ok, finally found the solution.

Probably due to lack of experience with ReactJS and web development...

```
    var Task = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      var percentage = this.props.children + '%';
      ....
        <div className="ui-progressbar-value ui-widget-header ui-corner-left" style={{width : percentage}}/>
      ...
```

I created the percentage variable outside in the render function.

Comment: You could also write something like `style={{width: this.props.value + "%"}}`.

Comment: Or even better, with a template string: `style={{width: \`${this.props.value}%\`}}`

Answer (score 4):

You can simply do this:

```
    <div className="ui-progressbar-value ui-widget-header ui-corner-left" 
      style={{width : `${this.props.value}%`}}/>
```

The width will be in percentage. e.g. `100%`/`50%`...