# How to change the position of the element dynamically in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am using ReactJs. I want to change a position of the image dynamically.

I am trying to set up style like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22291913/how-to-change-reactjs-styles-dynamically):

My sprite.js:

```
'use strict';
import '../res/my_css.css'

const React = require('react');
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

class Sprite extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var left = 5000 + 'px';
    var top = 5000 + 'px';
    var padding = 5000 + 'px';
    return (
        <div id="bird" style={{padding:padding, left: left, top:top}}/>
    )
  }
}

export default Sprite;
ReactDOM.render(
  <Sprite />,
  document.getElementById('sprite')
)
```

My css contains:

```
#bird {
  background:url('../res/bird.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I see the image, but `style={{padding:padding, left: left, top:top}}` does not applied.

If I look to the source code in Chrome, I see the style `padding:5000px, left:5000px, top:5000px`. But my image is in the left top corner.

How can I dinamically change the position of the div element (image in my case) in ReactJs?

Comment: Have you set `position: absolute;`? `top` and `left` will have no effect otherwise

Comment: @Hunter McMillen position: 'absolute' works, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like this.You have not included **position:absolute**

```
class Sprite extends React.Component {
      render() {
        var left = 5000 + 'px';
        var top = 5000 + 'px';
        var padding = 5000 + 'px';
        return (
            <div id="bird" style={{padding, left, top,position:'absolute'}}/>
        )
  }
}
```

Comment: that's exactly that I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To play with left and top add position like this

```
<div id="bird" style={{position: 'relative', padding, left, top}}/>
```

Comment: Is works. Although  I do not undestand how it works in using "padding, left, top" instead of "padding:padding, left: left, top:top,position" :)

Comment: Use property value shorthand in es6 so shorthand of "top: top" is "top"

Comment: Yes, ES6. In an object, if the key and value pair are same `{ name: name }`, you can just mention it once like `{ name }` or as done in the answer.