# Dynamically changing colors ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

Ok, I am fairly new to React so this is my problem.... I did manage to dynamically render 5 ball components, what I want to achieve  is that every time i click on the ball that ball change color and stay that way until a click again on that ball when it comes back to default color. And also to change colors of multiple balls,for example change color of 1 3 5, but again to bring back to default color when click on them again... Any thoughts?

```
.Ball {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    color: #3d3c3a;
    border-radius: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 0.5px #000;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer
}

 const balls = props => {
  return (
    <Aux>
      <p className={classes.Ball} id={props.id} onClick={props.clicked}>
        {props.number}
      </p>
    </Aux>
  );
};

class Game extends Component {
  state = {
    ids: [
      { id: 1 },
      { id: 2 },
      { id: 3 },
      { id: 4 },
      { id: 5 }
    ],
    chosenBallsIds: []
  };



  clickedBallHandler = ballIndex => {
    let chosenBallsIds = this.state.chosenBallsIds;
    if (chosenBallsIds.includes(ballIndex)) {
      let index = chosenBallsIds.indexOf(ballIndex);
      if (index > -1) {
        chosenBallsIds.splice(index, 1);
      }
    } else {
      chosenBallsIds.push(ballIndex);
    }

    if (chosenBallsIds.length >= 9) {
      chosenBallsIds.pop();
    }

    chosenBallsIds.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a - b;
    });

    this.setState({
      chosenBallsIds: chosenBallsIds
    });

  };


  render() {
    let balls = null;
    balls = (
      <div>
        {this.state.ids.map((ball, index) => {
          return (
            <Balls
              key={ball.id}
              number={ball.id}
              clicked={() => this.clickedBallHandler(index + 1)}
              id={index + 1}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );


    return (
      <Aux>
        <div className={classes.Balls}>{balls}</div>
      </Aux>
    );
  }
}

export default Game;
```

Comment: did you find a resolution?

Comment: Hey, no, I did not find any solutions...Did a whole bunch of other stuff in the same application an it is pretty much done ,just this... I am still looking for the solution. So I generate every ball with .map in render method and i save every clicked ball in chosenBallsIds array, but it not ringing any bell how to achieve to color the balls... Some more help?

Comment: Did you look at my post concerning dynamic properties for css? You could use a dynamic string, pass in a different value from your state, and pass values from an array of hex values in your state.

Comment: Yours would be similar to style={{`background-color: #${this.state.hex}`}}

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into [dynamic properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22291913/how-to-change-reactjs-styles-dynamically). This will allow you to set background-color differently for each click. Also, I would look into setting an array of hex colors, then when the user clicks, you can set state to a new item in the array, based on your needs. Your if statement is complex, and probably doesn't need to be.