# Apply dynamic css property to a div using the styled props

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I am new to react . Here I have a to give a border

```
border-bottom: 3px solid 'this will be dynamic'
```

Now,

```
<div className={classNames({ [css.bgStatusContainer]: true })}>
        <Buyinginfo buyingstat={buyingStatus}/>
```

```
.bgStatusContainer {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #71b900;
}
```

Now here I have hard-coded the color. Now, color is dependent on the type of status.

```
CLose - red
open -green
pre -orange
```

Can any one help me with this ?

Comment: JSX allows you to directly use js normally inside the constant of CSS styles. And third party libs allow you to use `Theme provider` which may also fit your demand

Comment: possible solution to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22292449/12522543)

Answer (score 2):

You could make the string dynamic as follows, in the example I've made key value pair for each of the 'type of status' that you've mentioned and incrementing `state.pos` over the array of keys each time to change the color:

```js
class Btn extends React.Component {
  state = { pos: 0 };
  obj = { close: 'red', open: 'green', pre: 'orange' };
  arr = ['close', 'open', 'pre'];

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ pos: (this.state.pos + 1) % 3 });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>click</button>
        <div style={{borderBottom: `3px solid ${this.obj[this.arr[this.state.pos]]}`}}>
          Buying Info
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Btn />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```