# how to change the react component css class value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Here is my App.js

```
import './App.css';
import './scripts/logic.js';
import Player from './components/Player'
import { useState } from 'react'
function App() {

  const [cordinate,setCordinate] = useState({x:"",y:""})

  function moveRight(){
    
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="container">
          <div className="board" id="board">
              <Player/>
          </div>
          <button>Move Right</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

my css file where the player css is defined

```
.player{
    background-color: red;
    grid-row-start: 5;
    grid-column-start:5;
}
```

Here what i want now by using the moveRight function i want to manipulate the value of player class `grid-row-start` and `grid-column-start` how can i achive this

Comment: use inline css for problem

Comment: how can i use that i mean even if i user that how will i manipulate it using code

Comment: ref this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22291913/how-to-change-reactjs-styles-dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use inline styling and pass your variables directly

```
<div className="container" style={{gridRowStart: cordinate.x, gridRowEnd: cordinate.y}}>
```

Please keep in mind that in your case you will need to pass cordinates down to Player component as a props and then use inline styling accordingly

Comment: i need to pass the style  in the player component  when i pass the style in my player component it does not render anything no style appear

Comment: You need to pass cordinates as a prop to Player component and inside player apply inline style to div element or any html element you contain everything, really

Answer (score 2):

you can use `styledcomponent` for this situation

but you can do it in your js file too
you should use inline style on the jsx tag like this

```
const [cordinate,setCordinate] = useState({x:"",y:""})


 function moveRight(){
    // change your state over here
  }

const tagStyle = {
    gridRowStart: cordinate.x,
    gridColumnStart: cordinate.y ,

}
<tag style={tagStyle}>
...
</tag>
```