# adding display to react component conditionally?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to hide the components conditionally

method 1:
to add style = display : none to div

is there a way to dynamically add display to div via state?

since all the components are in Div , how to isolate each rendered component and add display none ?

is there a way to add the state that can trigger css / add css to certain react component?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import all the component A, B AND C

class App extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
               <Component A/>
               <Component B/>
              <Component C/>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you show your condition?

Comment: @nos nart condition is when i find example: google in url

Answer (score 1):

This seems like partly a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22291913/how-to-change-reactjs-styles-dynamically).

You can set your values of a class dynamically like this:

```
renter() { 
  return (
    <div className={is_displayed ? "showItClassName" : "dontShowItClassName"} > 
      ...
    </div>
  );
```

This is probably the better way because you can re-use your css classes.  You can create variables ahead of time with the class name or call a function if you don't want the conditional in the middle of the html tag.

If your sure you want to use an style tag you need the extra curly braces.

```
render() {
  return (
    <div style={is_displayed ? {display:"block"}: {display:"none"}} >
           <Component A/>
           <Component B/>
          <Component C/>

    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Per [Choosing the Type at Runtime](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#choosing-the-type-at-runtime):

```
import { ComponentA } from './ComponentA';

<div>
  {(() => {
    // capitalized variable first
    let Component = <p>Error!</p>;
    if (/google/.test(this.state.url)) {
      Component = ComponentA
    }
    return <Component />
  })()}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can render the component conditionally instead of tto use css to make this:

```
{true_condition && ( <Component /> )}
```

Comment: but there are multiple components and i am trying to write only one condition and pass the css property to respective component to display @Junior Marques

Comment: The true_codition can be a string, like `state === "componenta"` and it render componentA.